# Почему func() не выполняется полностью, когда я прерываю работу вложенного sleep() удалением таймера?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, таймер, settimeout

Пытаюсь разобраться с асинхронностью (promise,async,await). Не понимаю, почему после нажатия на блок, func() не продолжает выполняться, сообщение "после sleep" не выводится в консоль. И как сделать, чтобы это сообщение все-таки выводилось.

```js
let timerId;

function deleteTimer(){
console.log("таймер остановлен");
clearTimeout(timerId);
}


function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => timerId=setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
 
async function func() {
  console.log("до sleep");
  await sleep(10000);
  console.log("после sleep");
}
 
func();
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    div {
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      background-color:aquamarine;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <div onclick="deleteTimer()">Нажми на меня</div>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я вас не понимаю, загрузил ваш код в песочницу, все отрабатывает нормально. При запуске кода у вас выводится "до sleep", затем активируется таймер. Если нажать на блок, таймер очищается. Если не нажимать, выполняется как надо.

Comment: я хочу, чтобы после запуска кода вывелось:
1) "до sleep" (в этот момент запустится таймер на 10 секунд), 
2) "таймер остановлен" после нажатия на блок, 
3) "после sleep".
Но последнего сообщения не выводится

Comment: Так у вас стоит await перед "после sleep", следовательно пока промис не отдаст результат успешно\неуспешно, функция будет ожидать. Ваше очищение таймера его просто чистит, не давая никакого результата для промиса.

Comment: Как мне сделать, чтобы промис отдавал успешный результат после нажатия на блок? Как лучше решить эту задачу?

Comment: Как вывести промис из состояния ожидания извне?

Comment: Честно, именно для ваших условий, я затрудняюсь ответить, но по факту такой ситуации, как у вас возникать не должно вообще. По факту можно было бы обернуть промис в еще один таймаут и на основе состояния промиса по прошествии этого времени делать return.

Comment: @MrYogurt, спасибо, ваш комментарий для меня полезен, подумаю на тем, как решить задачу иначе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если действительно нужно сделать что-то близкое к вашему коду, можно попробовать так:

```js
let timerId;
let outerResolve;

function deleteTimer() {
  console.log("таймер остановлен");
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  outerResolve();
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    outerResolve = resolve;
    timerId = setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
 
async function func() {
  console.log("до sleep");
  await sleep(10000);
  console.log("после sleep");
}
 
func();
```

```html
<body>
  <style>
    div#stop {
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      background-color:aquamarine;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="stop" onclick="deleteTimer()">Нажми на меня</div>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
```

Можно ещё попробовать [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

```js
function processClick() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    document.querySelector('div#stop').addEventListener(
      'click',
      () => {
        console.log("таймер остановлен");
        resolve();
      },
      { once : true });
  });
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
 
async function func() {
  console.log("до sleep");
  await Promise.race([
    sleep(10000),
    processClick(),
  ]);
  console.log("после sleep");
}
 
func();
```

```html
<body>
  <style>
    div#stop {
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      background-color:aquamarine;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="stop">Нажми на меня</div>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за 2 решения! То, что нужно :)

Comment: @Виктор Там ещё можно подчистить хвосты — убрать обработчик события по истечении таймера, например, но это уже детали, которые могли затмить суть)